# How to Move Databricks Catalog Schema with tables to another catalog in same workspace

Tags: sql, mysql, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

How to Move Databricks Catalog Schema with tables to another catalog in same workspace

whenever I am trying to move schema from one to another ,it is showing the below error

Query

```
%sql

CREATE or Replace TABLE 1data_catalog.test.sometable SHALLOW CLONE 2data_catalog.test.sometable;
```

ERROR

```
AnalysisException: [STREAMING_TABLE_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED.UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION] The operation CLONE is not allowed: The operation is not supported on Streaming Tables.
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SparkDriverExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [STREAMING_TABLE_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED.UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION] The operation CLONE is not allowed: The operation is not supported on Streaming Tables.
    at com.databricks.sql.StreamingTableErrors$.streamingTableOperationNotAllowed(StreamingTableErrors.scala:37)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisEdge$$anonfun$apply0$1.applyOrElse(DeltaAnalysisEdge.scala:123)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisEdge$$anonfun$apply0$1.applyOrElse(DeltaAnalysisEdge.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisEdge.apply0(DeltaAnalysisEdge.scala:103)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisEdge.apply(DeltaAnalysisEdge.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisEdge.apply(DeltaAnalysisEdge.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$4(RuleExecutor.scala:286)
```

How to solve this type of issue??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: is it matters? this is catalog that is getting steaming data ,i want to move that in another catalog, I am using AWS databricks